# formula writing for excel if/then

Tags: worksheet-function

Column D is a list of states. There are 3000 lines.

If column D is AL, GA, SC, FL, NC, TN, or MS then I want column G to say to say GA.

If column D is LA, TX, NM, OK, AR or NE column G should show TX

How can I write the IF THEN formula?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way is to group the states you want to check for in columns.

For example, you could put AL, GA, SC, FL, NC, TN, and MS in column **H**, and LA, TX, NM, OK, AR, NE in column **I**. Then, in column G put:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,H1:I6,1,FALSE),0)=1,"GA",IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,H1:I6,2,FALSE),0)=1,"TX"))
```

This looks for D1's value in the range of H1 through I6. First it looks in the 1st column of that range (column H). If nothing is found, it moves on to the second column in the range (column I). If nothing is found there, it returns a 0.

This could be modified to include other states and answers, but if you start getting more than a few options, I'd recommend putting a state name in the top row of each column you make as a header. Then you could write code to return that name in the top row of what you've found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` with the arrays built into the formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,{"AL","GA","SC","FL","NC","MS","TN"},0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,{"LA","TX","NM","OK","NE","AR"},0)),"","TX"),"GA")
```

This returns nothing if a match is not found in either list.